# MongoDB geoNear not returning any results

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-query

I have a geospatial collection which I am trying to query for results within a given range. When doing this I cannot figure out why my query returns the results array with no information. I have tried different ways of running this but always am presented with the same results. I need to know what I am doing wrong and can't find any reason out there as to why this shouldn't work.

Here is format of the documents in the collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54432bd85ae1e944d857659d"),
"FEATURE_ID" : 406,
"Location" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "Cement Trough Canyon",
        "mapName" : "Blue House Mountain",
        "class" : "Valley",
        "state" : "AZ",
        "county" : "Navajo",
        "retrieved" : false
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -110.5126118, 
            33.9950482
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
db.runCommand({
    geoNear: "gis",
    near: { type: "Point", 
    coordinates: [ -110.512612, 33.995048 ] },
    spherical: true
})
```

Here is the index I created for the collection:

```
{
"geometry" : "2dsphere"
}
```

Here are the results:

```
{
"results" : [],
"stats" : {
    "nscanned" : NumberLong(26),
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberLong(26),
    "avgDistance" : NaN,
    "maxDistance" : 0,
    "time" : 4
},
    "ok" : 1
}
```

According to this the query runs fine but it doesn't pick up any of the data from the object in the collection. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have geometry as a sub-field of Location, so when you run

```
db.gis.ensureIndex({"Location": "2dsphere"});
```

MongoDB creates the index on Location, as if this were the name of your geometry field, even though this field does not exist, and returns OK (which is a bit confusing, in my opinion). To illustrate further this gotcha, try this:

```
db.gis.ensureIndex({"i_do_not_exist": "2dsphere"});
```

which will return something like the following, depending on how many indexes you already had:

```
{
   "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
   "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
   "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
   "ok" : 1
}
```

The solution is to use dot notation to reference the embedded geometry field, ie,

```
db.gis.ensureIndex({"Location.geometry": "2dphere"});
```

then your query will return a result. See [indexes on sub documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/) section from the docs for more information.

Alternatively, you could restructure your document so that the geometry field is top level.

```
db.gis.insert({
  "_id" : ObjectId("54432bd85ae1e944d857659d"),
  "FEATURE_ID" : 406,
  "Location" : {
     "properties" : {
       "name" : "Cement Trough Canyon",
       "mapName" : "Blue House Mountain",
       "class" : "Valley",
       "state" : "AZ",
       "county" : "Navajo",
       "retrieved" : false
     }
  },
  "geometry" : {
     "type" : "Point",
     "coordinates" : [ 
        -110.5126118, 
         33.9950482
     ]
   }   
});

db.gis.ensureIndex({"geometry": "2dsphere"});

db.runCommand({
   geoNear: "gis",
   near: { type: "Point", 
   coordinates: [ -110.512612, 33.995048 ] },
   spherical: true
});
```

now returns the above record.